# Php ratchet websocket $conn->send($msg)! How to get this messenge in client?

Tags: php, websocket, autobahn, ratchet

Here my code (websocket php using rachet and wamp server!

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
  $conn->send("Close client");
}
```

I will using $conn->send() to send a message for all client but i don't know how to get this message using autobahnJS on client?

**Update**
i found sulutions for this problem!

1) enabled debug mode in autobahnJS

```
ab.debug( true, true );
```

2) using conn._websocket.onmessage for get every messenge response from server.

```
conn._websocket.onmessage = function (e){
    data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(data[1]);
    if(data.cat=='serverEvents'){
    switch(data.action) {
        case 'updateServerinfo':
              jQuery.updateServerinfo(data.actionData);
        break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

autobahnJS has its own way of handling client requests made to the server. You are trying to send a request from the server (a "close all clients" request) to all the clients. The best way to do this, would be to have a thread that's polling your server for events every X seconds, using JS's setInterval() function. e.g.:

setInterval(checkForUpdate, 60 * 1000);

and in checkForUpdate():

```
function checkForContentUpdate(timetableId) {
    var serviceUrl = 'http://yourscripttocheckhere';

    var xhr = $.ajax({url: serviceUrl, cache: false, success: function(content) {
      // Check server reply and act accordingly
    }});
}
```

Comment: AutobahnJS does not use AJAX but works over WebSocket (both for RPC and PubSub).

Answer (score 0):

With AutobahnJS you have 2 ways of interacting with server-side: RPC and PubSub. If you want to send a message from server to all clients, just subscribe to some topic X in all clients and publish to X from server.

Disclosure: I'm original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.